# Tabbing navigation issue in VC++ form when it’s opened from C# WinForms application

Tags: c#, .net, visual-c++

I have a C# application having various input controls(TextBox, ComboBox, Buttons etc.) along with a tab control. In one of the tabs I have an unmanaged C++ window embedded in it. The C++ windows has few input controls too.

Using tab key, I am able to navigate to C# controls witohut any issues. However when I select a control on the C++ window and press tab, it does not transfer the focus to the next control on the C++ window. Rather, it sets the focus to a control on a C# control.

As per the below post, if we have an embedded unmanaged form, at a managed level (C# application), the .NET control will be unaware it has any children.

[How can I embed an unmanaged C++ form into a .NET application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5156794/how-can-i-embed-an-unmanaged-c-form-into-a-net-application)

Is there any workaround for this?